# Getting resource string not found error while running JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I get below error while running script and execution is automatically stopped after running some threads. E.g I ran 1000 threads simultaneously and 926 tests were passed and then execution was stopped. I have used both JMeter 5.0 and 5.2 versions

```
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [#_samples]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [median]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [90%_line]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [95%_line]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [99%_line]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [min]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [error_%]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [throughput]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [received_kb/sec]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,341 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [sent_kb/sec]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,890 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [received_kb/sec]
2020-02-22 15:08:25,905 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [received_kb/sec]
```

Comment: Can you please give a screenshot of your script? Are you using gui or command line?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not an error, you're getting this message of [`WARN` severity](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) and it means that JMeter tries to find default value for these metrics in JMeter properties and fails. It doesn't have any negative impact on the results. If you don't want to see this you can [decrease JMeter logs verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for JMeterUtils class by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils" level="error" />
   ```
2. This is actually a well-known [JMeter bug #62770](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62770) so if you upgrade to the latest [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) you should stop seeing these warnings in any case.